# Straight Line Motion w/ Acceleration and Deceleration Rates?

Tags: calculus, integration, mathematical-physics

PROBLEM:

A subway train travels 400ft between two stations. It starts from rest and accelerates at the rate of 8ft/sec^2 until it's velocity reaches 20ft/sec. It then moves at this constant velocity for awhile and then decelerates to rest at the rate of 12ft/sec^2. Find the total time between the stations.

QUESTIONS:

I'm lost on how to approach this problem. I'm not for sure if I should set two acceleration expressions up and use integration to work backwards. Then somehow utilize both to arrive at (t).

I started with 8 as acceleration and used integration to get v as shown below.

(a) = 8

(v) = 8t + 20      NOTE: This seems wrong because initial velocity is technically 0ft/sec

400 = ?

Again, this can't be so and I'm stuck on how and where I should start implementing 20ft/sec and the other deceleration rate which is 12ft/sec^2. Can someone get me pointed in the right direction without giving me the complete answer.

Comment: Would the expression for (s) displacement, (v) velocity and (a) acceleration look like the following.(s)=4t^2-6t^2+400                                  (v)=8t-12t                                                (a)=8-12

Comment: Since _three_ accelerations are used during this trip, you must split the problem into three parts: the first, during which the acceleration was $+8 \text{ft/sec}^2$; the second (coasting) portion, when the acceleration is _zero_ ; and the third and final part, where the acceleration is $-12 \text{ft/sec}^2$.  The sum of the three distances traveled in these parts is 400 feet.

Comment: Some other things to think about, in view of the answer posted below:  How long does it take the train to accelerate from rest to 20 ft/sec?  How far will it move in that time?  How long does it take to decelerate back to rest?  How far does it go while decelerating?  How much of the trip was covered at 20 ft/sec?  How long would that take?  You now have the times for the three phases.

Answer (score 1):

I see someone has already answered this.

I tend to tell students to break up the problems according to differing acceleration/velocities and build an expression for the total time in terms of the known variables. Also if you use integration the correct expression for v would be
$$ v(t) - v(0) = \int_{0}^t a(t) dt  $$
Where you would use the fact that your initial condition is $v(0) = 0 $ to arrive at
$$ v(t) = 8t + v(0) = 8t $$
Then you might further integrate using the initial condition $x(0) = 0$ to obtain in a similar fashion
$$ x(t) - x(0) = \int_0^t v(t) = \frac{1}{2}at^2$$
$$ x(t) = \frac{1}{2}at^2 + x(0) = \frac{1}{2}at^2 $$
Which is the usual distance equation for a zero initial velocity/position.

However this is over complicating the problem because we already would have at our disposal the equations for constant acceleration:
\begin{eqnarray*}
x(t) &=& x_0 + v_0 t + \frac{1}{2}at^2  \\
v(t) &=& v_0 + at \\
v^2(t) &=& v^2(t_0) + 2 a \Delta x \\
\end{eqnarray*}
But yes the previous post is correct, simply separate the trip into three sections with different accelerations and solve for the individual times

Comment: I might add try doing some more thinking on the subject and if you get stuck just include the rest of your thought process.